# Ejecutar casos de prueba secuenciales en el mismo browser Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

Buen día para todos,
tengo una duda al usar selenium webdriver, y me gustaría saber como puedo ejecutar casos de prueba secuencialmente sin que se cierre el navegador, por ejemplo:

Supongamos que tengo los siguientes casos de prueba:
1. Login
2. Crear Pedido
3. Consultar pedido

Entonces son tres casos de prueba diferentes, donde el tercero depende del segundo, y el segundo depende del primero.

Mi problema es que cuando ejecuto el test suite, el primer caso pasa sin problemas, pero para el segundo se me cierra el navegador y me abre el otro, pero cuando intento crear el pedido, obviamente no esto logueado porque la sesión ya se ha perdido.

Entonces que podría hacer en este caso para ejecutar los casos de prueba secuencialmente uno tras otro sin cerrar o abrir otra vez el navegador?

Muchas gracias de antemano por toda la colaboración.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final solucioné mi problema de la siguiente manera

```
package test_suite;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import pageObjects.CreateNewStudyPage;
import pageObjects.LoginPage;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    LoginPage.class,
    CreateNewStudyPage.class,
    //OpenAllTabsAndExports.class
})

public class Test_Suite {   
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\WebDriver_Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://10.3.8.50");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void setDownClass() {
         driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Primer test que realiza la aplicación

```
package pageObjects;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import test_suite.Test_Suite;

public class LoginPage {


    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        WebDriver driver = Test_Suite.driver;
        driver.findElement(By.id("sponsorname")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("sponsorname")).sendKeys("Test");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("123");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-success")).click();
    }
}
```

Luego sin cerrar el browser, el test suite continua ejecutando el siguiente test

```
package pageObjects;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import test_suite.Test_Suite;

public class CreateNewStudyPage {
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Test
    public void testCreateNewStudy() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = Test_Suite.driver;

        if(isElementPresent(By.id("userMenu"), driver)) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dropdownMenu1']/i/i")).click();

            for (int second = 0;; second++) {
                if (second >= 30) fail("timeout");
                try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("//*[@id='userMenu']/div/ul/li[3]/a"), driver)) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userMenu']/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
        }
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add']"), driver)) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add']")).click();

        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try { if (isElementPresent(By.id("StudyCode"), driver)) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("StudyCode")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("StudyCode")).sendKeys("Study_Code_Automation28");
        driver.findElement(By.id("GSKBmarcref")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("GSKBmarcref")).sendKeys("BMARCREF");
        driver.findElement(By.id("StudyShortName")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("StudyShortName")).sendKeys("Short Name");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SvtVersionId"))).selectByVisibleText("1");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("BudgetTypeId"))).selectByVisibleText("Substudy");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("PhaseName"))).selectByVisibleText("I");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("PatientTypeId"))).selectByVisibleText("Inpatient");

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by, WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí la clave está en las primeras líneas de las clases donde se va a realizar el test, y es crear el driver asignandole el valor del driver de la clase Test Suite

**WebDriver driver = Test_Suite.driver;**

Y de este modo se usa siempre el mismo navegador para todos los tests que ejecute dentro del test suite.

Comment: Tengo una duda, cuando uso el webdriver dentro del test... aplicando tu misma solucion FALLA, sabes porque pueda ser?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de conseguir lo que propones. La mas simple, pero que va en contra de las buenas practicas del testing es tener los tres casos de prueba sobre la misma clase, 3 @Test, y en poner el driver.quit en el @afterclass. De esta manera el navegador se cerrará después de ejecutar todos los metodos.

Con la idea del primer paso, podrias tambien con TestNG crear dependencias entre los casos de prueba, es decir el caso 2 depende del 1 y el 3 del 2. De esta forma consigues que si, por ejemplo el login no funciona, las otras dos pruebas no se ejecuten, su estado seria 'Skiped'. TestNG tambien te permite utilizar la variable `context` de tipo ITestContext, donde puedes añadir propiedades. De esta forma puedes compartir variables entre diferentes casos de prueba.

Sin cambiar nada de como estan definidos los @beforeclass, @beforemethod y los @afterclass o @aftermethod, es que aunque tu tengas definidos 3 casos de prueba diferentes, a la hora de automatizarlos sea un unico test con todos los steps necesarios para que la prueba valide los 3 casos de prueba. Podrias añadir los assets correspondientes para validar que las pruebas 1 y 2 terminaron correctamente.

Comment: Buenas tardes j.barrio,
Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
La primera opción que propones, ya lo intenté y de hecho funciona, pero no lo quiero hacer de esa forma, precisamente por lo mismo que tu dices, porque va en contra de las buenas prácticas del testing y en una aplicación muy grande se volvería inmanejable.
Para la segunda y tercera opción, lastimosamente debo usar junit, entonces no me es viable, muchas gracias y se de pronto me puedes colaborar con alguna otra idea te lo agradecería muchísimo.
Saludos